# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: 7, database

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118
>   Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not
>   counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or
>   BLOBs:

Database storage Engine : Innodb

Do we have to switch over for MyIsam?

Comment: could you please provide more info on exactly in which scenario you encountered this error.

Comment: The reason of the error is because the uc_products['Ubercart Table'] table exceeds the limited size of innodb support.

Comment: InnoDB restricts row size to something less than half a database page (approximately 8000 bytes), not including VARBINARY, VARCHAR, BLOB, or TEXT columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a case of InnoDB File Format issues.

## **SUGGESTION #1**

If you are not using [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table), you may need to export all the data with mysqldump, delete ibdata and ib_logilfe0 and ib_logilfe0. Then, reimport that data. I wrote a [*detailed step-by-step process*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261) for this 2 years ago.

## **SUGGESTION #2**

Increase the size of your InnoDB Log Files. Each file (ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1) needs to be more than **10 times as big as the biggest BLOB** in your dataset:

Here are several links discussing this scenario

- https://serverfault.com/q/293406/69271
- https://serverfault.com/a/3979/69271
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39168

MySQL's maximum size of [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) for a log group of of 2 files is 2047M. Should you ever need InnoDB Log Files that can exceed the 4GB combined barrier, you must upgrade to Percona Server.

I also wrote a [*detailed step-by-step process*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265) for resizing InnoDB Log Files.

## **SUGGESTION #3 (OPTIONAL)**

You may want to switch the [**innodb_file_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format) to Barracuda. [*Bill Karwin's answer in the DBA StackExchange*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6599/877) and links thereof explains why.

Comment: Faced this issue when installing Drupal 8 with a translation. Increasing "innodb_log_file_size" fixed the problem. Thanks!